# Arduino to Python: How to import readings using ser.readline() into a list with a specified starting point?

Tags: python, arrays, raspberry-pi, uart, usart

This is quite a specific query so please bear with me.

I have 14 ultrasonic sensors hooked to an Arduino sending live readings to the serial monitor (or Pi when I plug it in) . The readings are sent as follows, *with a new line between every 2 digits* (except Z).

> Z
> 62
> 61
> 64
> 63
> 64
> 67
> 98
> 70
> 69
> 71
> 90
> XX
> 75
> XX

These measurements are in cm. "XX" implies the reading is out of the two digit range. Z has been assigned as a starting point as the pi reads the sensors very fast and repetitively, to the point of 80 readings in a second or so. So ser.readline() gives multiple samples of the same sensors

When python reads the readings in ser.readline() it does not have a starting point. It may start at 70, XX or Z. I want to assign it into an accessible list so that:

> array [0] = Z *(always)*
>
> array [1] = 62 *(first two digits)*
>
> array [2] = 61 *(second two digits)*
>
> ..
>
> array [14] = XX *(fourteenth two digits)*

This is my code which unfortunately doesn't work as list is out of range:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)

print ("Start")

overallcount=1 #initialise 2 counters
arraycount =1
array = [] #initialise 2 lists
line = []

while True:
    while overallcount<30: #read 30 random readings from Arduino
        ser.readline()      
        print(str(overallcount)) #print reading number
        while arraycount<15:     #Number of readings to fill the array to be made
            for line in ser.readline():
                if line == 'Z':         #If element in ser.readline is "Z"
                    array[0] == line    #Assign first list element as Z (starting point)              
                arraycount=arraycount+1 #Iterate through until 14 sensors are read
            arraycount=1                #reset counter
        overallcount=overallcount+1     #Iterate through 30 random Arduino readings
    overallcount=1                      #iterate random counter
```

If you could please tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a better method for this I'd really really appreciate it!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Note that your checks overallcount<30 and arraycount<15 should really be overallcount<=30 and arraycount<=15.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)

readings = [] # Array to store arrays of readings
reading_id = 1 # Id of current reading
random_lines_expected = 30 # NUmber of random lines
num_sensors = 14 # Number of sensors

def read_random():
    for _ in range(random_lines_expected):
        ser.readline() 

read_random() # Read initial random lines
while True:
    print "Reading #", reading_id
    reading = [] # Initialize an array to collect new reading
    while ser.readline().strip() != 'Z': # Keep reading lines until we find 'Z'
        pass
    reading.append('Z') # Add Z to reading array
    for _ in range(num_sensors): # For 14 sensors...
        reading.append(ser.readline().strip()) # Add their value into array
    readings.append(reading) # Add current reading to the array or readings
    reading_id += 1 # Increment reading ID
    #read_random() #Uncomment this if random follows each series of readings
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It worked without errors and I've tested them via print reading. May you have a glorious day sir/maam

Comment: That's great, because I have not tried running it. Also, can you please accept the answer? Thanks and good luck with your project!